# How to get row height using Monotouch?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, height, row

I have a table view with rows (custom cells). If user tap on row, row's height changes (using ReloadRows and overrided GetHeightForRow methods).
I want to change row's height back when user taps already selected row.

Is it possible to get previous height in overrided GetHeightForRow() method? That should resolve a problem.

It's just like expand/collapse, but I don't know exactly how to implement it right and simply..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should remember the last select row in your UITableViewDelegate, if it's the same row you have to collapse the row.

Something like this:

```
        public override void RowSelected (
            UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (selectedRow == indexPath.Row)
            {
                Collapse();
            }
            else
            {
                Expand();
            }

            selectedRow = indexPath.Row;

            Console.WriteLine(
                "TableViewDelegate.RowSelected: Label={0}",
                 list[indexPath.Row]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW, how to change row's height not using GetHeightForRow?

Comment: There are two ways to set the row height. Set the `tableView.RowHeight` which is for all rows or the `GetHeightForRow`. There you can set different heights for the rows